# Cooldown on hacking the same portal?

Tags: ingress

If you try to hack a portal the 2nd time in a short time, you get a message, "The portal is hot" and has a 300 second delay. But it seems you always start with a 300 second delay. This afternoon, I was at a bus stop with 2 portals in range.  I hacked one and recharged it, then I did the same to the other.  I tried hacking the first one again, and I got a 300 second delay, while it clearly was 1 to 2 minutes later then I previously "re-hacked" a portal.

So I was wondering if this delay was just for me **and** if it was like a penalty for hacking the portal in such a short time. My philosophy is the hidden cooldown might just be two minutes and when "rehacking" on 1:59 you get a 300 second delay on top of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hacking delay is personal and it is always 300 seconds long. The message shown though only changes when you have remaining 240, 120, 60, 30 and 10 seconds. So, if you keep trying to hack in the first minute, you'll keep getting the "300 seconds remaining" message.

All your successful hacks will trigger this 5 minutes delay. On top of that your first Hack triggers a 4 hours cooldown. After your 4th consecutive successful Hack on that portal it will be "burned down" and will prevent further hacks until the four hours have passed. This cooldown too is personal, to prevent its use as an attack (burning down all the portals in an area to prevent enemy hacks)

Comment: There also appears to be a kind of bug or race condition, where you can hack a portal up to four times without cooldown in between. But I had this only once, it's very rare.

Comment: @Sentry It's typically called "multihacking", and I see it all the time; probably 1 in 15 hacks works, and I've gotten six in a row before hitting the cooldown

Comment: There are now portal mods that affect this behavior. Heat Sink mods reduce the 300 second cool down time. Multi hacks delay portal burn-out, allowing you some extra hacks in the same 4 hour window. The extent of these effects depends on the mod's rarity.

Answer (score 5):

Adding a liitle more of information @Kappei's answer,

-Other Time that show is 5 secs.
-Sometimes, if you hack, and just when the bounty appears, click on "Accept" and hack again, the portal will give you another hack. In my "team" we saw 6 hacks one after other. But the usual is only to have 1 per 5 minutes. Just try, what I said, because, sometimes you can get some surprise.

-With the last update in few days Niantic will leak the new Mods (5 in total), one of them allows you one hack more than usual (4-->5) and other downgrade the 5 minutes waiting to 4. (1 minute less)